# Were there any parallel port keyboards?

Tags: keyboards, ports

I was reading this QA ( [Why is the clock frequency of the PS/2 keyboard protocol so high?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15607/why-is-the-clock-frequency-of-the-ps-2-keyboard-protocol-so-high) ) and read in the replies that a high frequency was chosen (at least in-part) to reduce the latency between a keypress and the computer receiving the event.

I wondered *what if* a keyboard interface was designed using a clock-less parallel port interface to the computer (by "parallel port", I mean any cable or connection using parallel data lines, not just a PC parallel printer port).

For example, one using 8 data conductors to represent a 7-bit scan code and a 1-bit Pressed/Not-pressed state bit. Each change in the data lines would be triggered immediately on any change in physical keyboard state. This could hypothetically be done entirely with analog circuity, so no need for clock signal or polling. This means it would also support unlimited N-key rollover.

The host-device would be responsible for tracking keypress state, but it would only need 127 hardware bits. It would raise the CPU/OS keyboard interrupt when a keyboard state-change was sensed on the port's lines.

(This approach wouldn't preclude port multiplexing either. Just add additional bits to represent a device-ID).

I did a quick-search online for "parallel port keyboard" and "scsi port keyboard" but I didn't find anything relevant.

---

Somewhat related: my primary-school in the UK had BBC Micros and some of them had [concept-keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_keyboard) attached to them (probably [this exact model](http://chrisacorns.computinghistory.org.uk/8bit_Upgrades/ConceptKbd_A4-128.html), actually). I remember it having a blue casing and a ribbon cable attaching it to the computer. So I suppose that's one example but it's not a "true" keyboard.

AFAIK, while the "user port" was a parallel port, it did require polling by software instead of being capable of raising hardware keyboard interrupts.

Comment: I guess the obvious practical reason is that ribbon cables are fragile and can't be arranged neatly unless they are the correct length to go in a straight line between the two connectors, and something like a parallel printer cable would be too stiff to position the keyboard anywhere you wanted on a slippery desk top, unless the keyboard was built into a metal box that was heavy enough to stay where it was put..

Comment: The Presfax 100 appears to have a different interface, and the "6 wire ribbon cable" mentioned in the link would  not support parallel data transfer.

Comment: Note that the question has a specific criterion -- that a *scancode* is transmitted on the parallel interface, rather than scan rows and columns -- which may disqualify most examples of keyboards with parallel interfaces.

Comment: @DrSheldon I wasn't being specific about it sending a scancode down the line. It's just the only way I could think of implementing a clockless keyboard communication protocol for a parallel connection.

Comment: Why are you requiring the interface to be "clockless"? The keyboard controller still needs to scan a matrix, so there'll be a clock in the keyboard anyway. Requiring scancodes and key up/down information (rather than just "key pressed") further limits the range. Many early machines, including the original Apple II, had ASCII keyboards, which gave you the 7 bit parallel ASCII code of keys pressed.

Comment: @alephzero The C-128D keyboard *did* effectively use a 25-pin parallel printer cable. And yes, it was quite unwieldy. The keyboard itself didn't contain any logic, the cable had separate connections for each row and column, the scanning was done by the computer itself.

Comment: The BBC Micro user port can generate interrupts. It consists of 6522 VIA Port B pins PB[7:0] and Control lines CB1 and CB2, along with 5V and ground. The 6522 can be configured to use CB1 and CB2 as interrupt request inputs. Internally, the BBC Micro does just that with other 6522 VIA Control lines.

Comment: There's quite a few homecomputers that used this approach for an internal keyboard, either with a "scancode" or even exposing rows and columns of the keyboard matrix. For an external keyboard, the issue is the number of wires needed.

Comment: I would argue that the ASR-33 TTY had a "parallel" interface between keyboard and printer.

Comment: @Daj "using 8 data conductors to represent a 7-bit scan code and a 1-bit Pressed/Not-pressed state bit. ... entirely with analog circuity ... unlimited N-key rollover" -- ummh, how exactly did you mean that would work? You can't encode more than 128 states with 7 bits, and there's 650 two-letter combinations already. It'd would need some serialisation. And probably some memory to remember which keys were down to be able to produce the not-pressed states. Perhaps not something you'd want to do with just basic logic.

Comment: Now, you could make the keyboard just a big [priority encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_encoder), though. But it wouldn't support rollover at all, it'd just show the "most important" key of all those pressed. Or a one-hot to binary encoder without priority, in which case simultaneous keypresses would just produce garbage.

Comment: @ilkkachu In my post I suggested that the keyboard would set the data-lines to the scan code of the last-changed key (and its is-pressed state), and have the host computer be responsible for remembering state. So yes, there would be serialization, but it's done "for free" - and hypothetically my proposal would fall-apart completely if a user was able to press two keys simultaneously if the host computer could not tell them apart. There are also potential timing-issues with the data-lines rising/falling times, and many other issues - I don't want to get into specifics, intentionally :)

Comment: @Dai. yes, uneven rise/fall times of the data lines are another problem that clocks are made to solve... Perhaps I'm confused by the mention of "triggered immediately" and "analog circuitry", they make me think if just dummy (combinatorial?) logic in the keyboard and that doesn't seem to translate well into detecting which key was last pressed.

Comment: This seems to be evolving from a 'what if' question into a fairly wild let's-do-it-this-way-at-all-costs design exploration :-) I know they're fun but what's the point of the expense of such a keyboard circuit and where's it going?

Comment: @MichaelGraf: Note that the Apple II keyboard returned the scan code, with bit 4 sometimes xor'ed with the shift keys, and bit 6 being the "nor" of bit 5 and the control key. The keyboard matrix was laid out in ASCII order, but the electronics did no scan-code to ASCII translation except with regard to bits 4 and 5.

Comment: During my own hunt I found [this fun thread](http://www.vcfed.org/forum/showthread.php?66124-PS-2-to-parallel-keyboard-project) about creating a PS/2 to parallel translator that might be a fun read for you. In that thread is [this link](http://www.go4retro.com/products/ps2-encoder/) to an existing product that performs the translation.

Comment: @HotLicks: no; local echo (when used) on Teletypes was feeding back the _serial_ output from the keyboard distrbutor to the receiver (printer and/or punch) distributor. However some special function keys, typically 'local CR' and 'local LF', did connect directly, and mechanically.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Yep, I misstated.  The "parallel interfaces" were between keyboard and encoder, and between decoder and printer.  And I'm trying to recall how the Selectrics were combobulated.

Comment: Plain-typewriter Selectrics had each keybar set a few (6?) 'bails' which then controlled tilt-and-rotate of the golfball. For terminals (2741 and 52-something) and the mag-tape or mag-card word-processing versions, keypresses were detected and transmitted or recorded, but not echoed electrically. And there was a kludgy proportional-spacing variant, the Selectric Composer, used (for a while) by the school newspaper where I worked, that could be mounted on a (primitive) computer fitted with 50-odd solenoid-driven metal hooks to pull down each key(!)

Answer (score 24):

Early Wang basic computers used a *backplane* keyboard with an enormous bespoke parallel interface to the detached style keyboard device.

Wang's 2200 and 2600 BASIC-only minicomputers were available with the 2215 BASIC keyword KBD, the 2222 alphanumeric typewriter KBD, and the 2223 upper/lower case BASIC keyword KBD. None of these keyboards contained a key scanner in the peripheral itself -- Wang Labs found the scanner too bulky to slip under the keys -- so the scanner was in the peripheral controller that plugged into the backplane. The keyboard peripheral contained only the keys connected via diodes to a scannable matrix.

The matrix rows and columns, plus a few switches and lights and some signal housekeeping, were connected to the controller with a bundle of wires. That's right, a parallel connection to each row and column of keys. The wires, about 30 of them, were bundled into a kind of 3/8" gray plastic hose with robust strain reliefs at both ends.

This had the effect you would expect. You couldn't move the keyboard around without knocking things off your desk. Sometimes the keyboard would creep about under the influence of the stiff cable. I think the thing had weights in it to hold it down.

Comment: This answer certainly is an example of a *parallel port keyboard*.  However, the question specifically asks for a *scancode* (rather than the rows and columns of a matrix) transmitted on the parallel lines.  This answer does not meet that specific criterion in the question.  (Although I am skeptical that there was any system which met that criterion.)

Comment: @DrSheldon I've updated my question to make it clear that the idea of using scancodes was only an example.

Comment: @Dai: The Apple II keyboard should meet that criterion.  The keyboard yields ASCII, but that's because the key matrix is laid out in ASCII order.

Answer (score 24):

Of the variants produced in a relatively large series - let me remind you about the keyboard connection on the Commodore 128D - it was connected using a 25-pin interface, 23 lines of which directly represented the matrix of keys.
[image]

Comment: Do you have a pinout for the connector? 23 lines for the matrix? That makes no sense. Theoretically could be as few as 7 (for up to 128 keys). Practically, 3 for row (up to 8 rows, and there are only 6 rows including the lone spacebar) and 5 for column (up to 32 columns, far more than this keyboard) = 8 pins. So 23 is either an incredibly inefficient layout **or** includes other stuff - alternating ground pins? feedback of some sort?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact There's *no* logic in the keyboard, not even an encoder / decoder :-). It's an 8x11 matrix (= 19 pins), plus three extra pins for the locking 40/80 and caps lock keys and restore (giving 22 pins), plus GND, plus 2x N/C. That's it.

Comment: Very similar to the Wang minicomputer technology. Judging by the picture, Commodore was able to achieve a thinner and presumably more flexible cable than Wang Labs did.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact There's a pin-out at http://oldcomputer.info/8bit/c128/51.gif

Comment: Looks similar to the 23-pin D-connector they used in the SX-64

Comment: Except, it's not a parallel keyboard, but a simple Matrix. The C64/128 does not use a decoder, but two ports active scanned by the CPU.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, perhaps a differential signal?  That by it's nature doubles the needed lines.

Answer (score 10):

Early micro/home computer used parallel keyboards. These were (usually) called 'ASCII' Keyboards. A good example is **the Apple II, which implements a protocol almost exact like you imagined** - sans interrupt that is. A key press was presented as 7 data bits with ASCII like encoding plus a flag at bit 7 indicating a key press, cleared whenever the port was read.

Like serial keyboards they need decoding 'intelligence' able to turn some input matrix into a keyboard word. The [Apple II](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12510/12511#12511) for example use used a [MM5740 encoder](http://matthieu.benoit.free.fr/cross/data_sheets/National_Semiconductor_Data_Update6.pdf) originally designed for a TTY-like keyboard delivering a simple 7/8 bit plus strobe output. Others, like the [Intel 8279](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8279) offered a direct microprocessor compatible interface with higher functions.

---

Direct scanned keyboards are often mistaken for being parallel. **But they are not**. They are simply a matrix. Many home computers tried to save cost of a keyboard controller/decoder by using *some* parallel port to 'manually' decode a keyboard matrix. A good example is Commodore's PET series, all the way to the C128.

---

In general a **serial interfaces** did prevail as they need way less wires in your cable (if detached) and less port bits on the host side - similar leaving more port bits on the keyboard controller side. A great pre micro example are DEC terminal keyboards (copied by the Apple LISA keyboard). Many micros used the inherent advantages, IBM-PC, Amiga or Atari ST - the later used for example the 'freed' controller bits for the joystick interface.

Comment: I wonder if there were any keyboard designs that sought to minimize the number of wires without externally decoding keys, e.g. by having a scanning counter which would run until it either found a key was pushed or it reached the end of count, but which could be nudged to restart it until the next keypress or end of count.  Such a design could be fairly easily accommodated using 3-4 chips on the keyboard side, and a counter with 3-state outputs and a controllable open-collector output on the host side.  Host would read the counter until it is stopped, then strobe and release its output...

Comment: ...and then watch to see where the counter stops next.  If two consecutive stops are separated by 64 or 128 (depending upon counter length), no keys are pushed, and the host's counter will report the no-keys value (eliminating the need to hardware-synchronize the counters).

Answer (score 6):

For a keyboard that includes a shift key to be useful, either the CPU must poll it often enough to observe the state of the shift key whenever another key is pushed, or the keyboard must capture enough information without CPU intervention to know whether a keystroke represents a shifted or unshifted character.

In systems that use the former approach, there's not much benefit to having hardware report scan codes versus having the software directly perform row/column scanning.  In systems that use the latter approach, but only try to capture one key event (e.g. the Apple II) using a key matrix which is arranged in ASCII order, and applying the effects of shift and control keys before latching a key stroke, is cheaper than separately latching the main key and the state of the modifier keys.  On the PC and AT, a microcontroller in the keyboard includes enough internal buffering to ensure that changes to the modifier key states will be reported in sequence with respect to changes in any other keys' states, but using a microcontroller means a serial interface may be used as easily as a parallel one.

Answer (score 4):

The LINC (**L**aboratory **In**strument **C**omputer), the first computer I programmed in 1965, had a one-key rollover. When a key was pressed on its Soroban Engineering keyboard, a solenoid locked that key down and all the other keys up, sending a signal to the computer. Whatever computer program was running could then take its time (sometimes a sizable fraction of a second) to get around to polling the keyboard using the KBD instruction. The 6-bit keycode would then be read (yes, in parallel) by the computer and the keyboard lock disabled by that instruction. This scheme, while not supporting touch typing, at least ensured that keystrokes were read without any possibility of error.

It didn't take as many keystrokes to write programs for the LINC, since program locations were encoded as a letter and numeric digit combination (giving 260 possible program labels for each program), and most instructions were three or five characters long.

If no program was running (the LINC could be in the HALTed state), pressing a key would simply lock the key down until you released it manually by pressing a reset button in back of the keyboard.

Later designs switched to the Teletype KSR 35 and 37 floor keyboard console models which, while far more complex mechanically, at least had no keyboard locking mechanism. They may have included serial to parallel conversion, as they contained a motor that scanned the keys to generate the keycode.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINC#Keyboard

Comment: Teletype series 30 keyboards had a coded lever on each key which, when depressed, activated or deactivated codebars for the 7 ASCII bits (8 if parity); the positions of those codebars were then serialized by a motor+clutch-driven distributor. Those keyboards did _interlock_ so you couldn't depress two keys at once (except special cases like SHIFT) but were not locked by the 'remote' system (although on ASR models the _tape reader_ could be stopped and started from remote).

Comment: Why they used motors and other such complicated mechanisms? Could not they use a few transistors instead?

Comment: Transistors were either very expensive or not yet invented when Teletype and Soroban designed their mechanical keyboards. Plus. there was a rather long history of mechanical keyboards already, based on Baudot (5-bit) encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly a parallel interface, but the TRS-80 (models 1, 3 and 4) had a *memory mapped* keyboard! 8 address lines were matrixed to 8 data lines by the keys (and some diodes). The keyboard scan routine would start by looking at 0x38FF and if it got back 0x00 then no keys were pressed. If non-zero it would check 0x3801, 0x3802, 0x3804, up to 0x3880 and check each result to figure out what keys were pressed. It did 2-key rollover and debounce in software. My favorite code used PEEK(14400) to check state of the 4 arrow keys, space, and enter (perfect for flying spaceships or what have you). 42 years later that address is still something I remember.

[edit] I just saw that "direct scanned" was covered above. Since I expanded slightly on how they work, I'll leave this here.

Answer (score 2):

My first computer was a Big board by Fregusion. It ran CP/M and had a parallel keyboard as one of three console options (The others being a rs232 keyboard or a rs232 console). Since it was a kit It did not come with a keyboard (or power supply, crt, floppy drives, etc.) but expected ascii (or eight bit, one keyboard had a binary key which was wired to a 8x dip switch whet could send any value) and shift and control were handled by the keyboard. no key rollover was possible. If memory serves it was eight data lines plus strobe, but I haven't looked at it's schematics since the 90s. The main advantage of this is that the host required no processing for the keyboard beyond a port read.

Comment: Did the company actually design or sell such a keyboard, or was the end user supposed to come up with it themselves?

Comment: @DrSheldon, as I said, It was a kit so there was no standard keyboard, but there were a number of existing commercial off the shelf keyboards that could be used with minimal modification.

Answer (score 2):

The [IBM 1130](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_1130) used a keyboard mechanism from a keypunch. It constructed a 12 bit code for each key press [mechanically](http://www.righto.com/2017/12/repairing-1960s-era-ibm-keypunch.html), in parallel. The code was the sparse character code used on punched cards. The keyboard driver translated this to 8-bit [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).

When computers were built from discrete transistors (or even vacuum tubes), serial interfaces were rare unless the keyboard was a teletype machine. Serial->parallel conversion required hundreds of expensive transistors.